# "ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:" need fix

Tags: python, pip, python-module, pyaudio, portaudio

I am trying to make a voice assistant in python

i have been scratching my head for a month or 2 by now
here is my code with isues:

````
```
import speech_recognition as sr
# giving greeting functions
def wishMe():
    hour = datetime.datetime.now().hour
    if hour >= 0 and hour < 12:
        speak("Hello,Good Morning")
        print("Hello,Good Morning")
    elif hour >= 12 and hour < 18:
        speak("Hello,Good Afternoon")
        print("Hello,Good Afternoon")
    else:
        speak("Hello,Good Evening")
        print("Hello,Good Evening")


def takeCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        audio = r.listen(source)
```
````

here is the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 108, in get_pyaudio
    import pyaudio
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Voice Assistant\Voice Assistant.py", line 66, in <module>
    statement = takeCommand().lower()
  File "C:\Voice Assistant\Voice Assistant.py", line 43, in takeCommand
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 79, in __init__
    self.pyaudio_module = self.get_pyaudio()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 110, in get_pyaudio
    raise AttributeError("Could not find PyAudio; check installation")
AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation

Process finished with exit code 1
```

when i dove a little deeper this is what i found:

```
try:
    import pyaudio
except ImportError:
    raise AttributeError("Could not find PyAudio; check installation")
from distutils.version import LooseVersion
if LooseVersion(pyaudio.__version__) < LooseVersion("0.2.11"):
    raise AttributeError("PyAudio 0.2.11 or later is required (found version {})".format(pyaudio.__version__))
return pyaudio
```

when i tried installing the module this is what happend:

```
C:\Users\username >pip install pyaudio
Collecting pyaudio
  Downloading PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
  Building wheel for pyaudio (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-oijw55t3\\pyaudio_ef3a4852614643949811c737559924db\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-oijw55t3\\pyaudio_ef3a4852614643949811c737559924db\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-4tcqz_1o'
       cwd: C:\Users\mayan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-oijw55t3\pyaudio_ef3a4852614643949811c737559924db\
  Complete output (17 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  running build_ext
  building '_portaudio' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMS_WIN64=1 -Ic:\python39\include -Ic:\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
  _portaudiomodule.c
  c:\python39\include\pyconfig.h(117): warning C4005: 'MS_WIN64': macro redefinition
  src/_portaudiomodule.c: note: see previous definition of 'MS_WIN64'
  src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio
  Running setup.py clean for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
    Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-oijw55t3\\pyaudio_ef3a4852614643949811c737559924db\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-oijw55t3\\pyaudio_ef3a4852614643949811c737559924db\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-hnn7qujd\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\python39\Include\pyaudio'
         cwd: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-oijw55t3\pyaudio_ef3a4852614643949811c737559924db\
    Complete output (17 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMS_WIN64=1 -Ic:\python39\include -Ic:\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
    _portaudiomodule.c
    c:\python39\include\pyconfig.h(117): warning C4005: 'MS_WIN64': macro redefinition
    src/_portaudiomodule.c: note: see previous definition of 'MS_WIN64'
    src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\mayan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-oijw55t3\\pyaudio_ef3a4852614643949811c737559924db\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-oijw55t3\\pyaudio_ef3a4852614643949811c737559924db\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-hnn7qujd\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\python39\Include\pyaudio' Check the logs for full command output.
```

I also noticed the same message with different modules.

**

> *facts:*
>
> pip version: pip 21.0.1
>
> python version: python 3.9
>
> IDLE: Pycharm, publisher: jetbrains
>
> Directory: "C:\Voice Assistant"
>
> OS :Windows
>
> Windows version: Windows 10 Home

**

what i tried:

> pip install setuptools
>
> pip upgrade setuptools

what i expect:

> installation only using pip
>
> download latest non beta version

Thank You For You Assistance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+fatal+error+C1083%3A+Cannot+open+include+file%3A+%27portaudio.h%27%3A+No+such+file+or+directory

Comment: nah - did not work